# Inclusion of $1$-presheaves into $\infty$-presheaves preserves pushouts?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, topos-theory, limits-and-colimits

Let $\mathcal{R}$ be a $1$-category. Assume that one has a pushout of representable $1$-presheaves $\mathrm{y} A \cup_{\mathrm{y} B} \mathrm{y} C$ in $\mathsf{PSh}(\mathcal{R})$. Under which conditions does then the inclusion $\mathsf{PSh}(\mathcal{R}) \to \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{R})$ into $\infty$-preheaves preserve this pushout?

The reason why I am asking this, is the claim in Notation 8.3 of [Barwick‘s and Schommer-Pries‘ unicity paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.0040.pdf#page19) which says that a specific class (called $S_{0}$) of specific morphisms in $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{R})$ induced by some pushouts in $\mathcal{R}$ is the essential image under the above functor of a similarly defined class in $\mathsf{PSh}(\mathcal{R})$. For that to make sense, I think that the above must hold for the pushouts appearing there. Note also that in the situation, we know that the pushout $A \cup_{B} C$ exists in $\mathcal{R}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The inclusion from discrete presheaves to spaces doesn't preserve all pushouts, even when $\mathcal R$ is a point.

But it does preserves some pushouts. The usual condition is to check that at least one of $yB \to yA$ or $yB \to yC$ is a levelwise monomorphism of sets. Then because the Kan-Quillen model structure is left proper with monomorphisms for cofibrations, it follows that the pushout is a levelwise pushout of spaces, and hence a pushout of presheaves of spaces.

Note that for $yB \to yA$ (say) to be a levelwise monomorphism of sets is equally for $B \to A$ to be a monomorphism in $\mathcal R$.

I haven't checked carefully, but I suspect that this criterion suffices to imply that all the pushouts considered by Barwick and Schommer-Pries are preserved by the inclusion from discrete presheaves to presheaves of spaces.

Comment: In general, a span of sets $A \leftarrow B \to C$ is naturally thought of as an undirected bipartite graph, with vertices $A \amalg C$ and edges $B$. The pushout in spaces is the geometric realization of this graph, homotopy equivalent to a disjoint union of wedges of copies of $S^1$, and the pushout in sets is $\pi_0$ of this space. So the pushout is preserved by the inclusion from sets to spaces if and only if there are no (undirected) cycles in the bipartite graph. For the inclusion from discrete presheaves to space presheaves, this condition should be checked levelwise.